# Why i get "XML Parsing Error: junk after document element" error in load() jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to load HTML and PHP content from **exhtml.php** to index page using **.load()** jquery function .
This is my jquery code :

```
$('#newhd').load('exhtml.php');
```

And this is index.html code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
     <!--Import materialize.css
     <link type="text/css" href="test.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

     <meta charset="UTF-8">

     <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

   </head>

   <body>
     <div id="newhd">

     </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components.js"></script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

And this exhtml.php file :

```
    <h2>This is a header !</h2>
<div class="hh">
  <h2>This is a header !</h2>
</div>
```

I see the result in my index page but i get this error in the console :
**XML Parsing Error: junk after document element**

Comment: What is the DOCTYPE of `exhtml.html`?

Comment: `exhtml.html` or `exhtml.php`?

Comment: I edited my question . now ?

Comment: Are you sending content-type headers in the PHP file?

Comment: No . i writed all my exhtml.php codes in this question .

Comment: The result is not a valid XML document, but `load()` doesn't assume your content is XML so some code is missing.

Comment: When i change exhtml.php suffix to .html , I get this error again !